# How to get the lowest ID from the last 10 records in a MYSQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

I have a simple articles table and want to select the lowest ID from the last 10 records. For example if there are `11` ids, the resulted id should be `2` and if there are `10` ids the resulted id should be `1` and so on.

I tried the following query on a table with `11` ids and it's outputting `1` while it should output `2`

```
SELECT MIN(id) FROM kisses ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a subquery and then use the MIN:

```
SELECT MIN(ID) 
FROM (SELECT ID
   FROM Articles
   ORDER BY ID DESC
   LIMIT 10
) t
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d835/1).

How about this, even easier:

```
SELECT ID
   FROM Articles
   ORDER BY ID DESC
   LIMIT 9,1
```

More fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d835/8

Good luck.

Comment: Aren't subqueries slow?? I think they don't perform well on scaling or am i wrong?? thanks :)

Comment: If i use the this query `SELECT id FROM kisses ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10`, do you know in PHP PDO statements how can I select the latest result (because it will be the latest id)?

Comment: While you want to avoid subqueries most of the time, since you are compressing it in to one result it will scale just fine. The risk of subqueries is if mainly if you were to do something which needed that subquery to be run multiple times. The subquery solution basically does 2 queries. If you did something with the subquery in a place which caused it to run multiple times, you wind up doing something that is m*n, which doesn't scale well. Though, the subquery-less solution is even better. =)

Comment: @samanime do you mean for example if i select multiple rows using a query with a subquery and loop them through a while loop...that would cause the problem??

Comment: @MichaelSamuel What it means it that the first query above doesn't make any sense. It's like using a loop to add `10` (in incrementals of `1`) to some variable instead of simply doing `$var += 10;`.

Comment: @sgeddes there is now another problem, what about if the table has less than 10 ids, the query will return 0 results although it should return id number 1 or the lowest id present...thanks :)

Comment: That's additional business logic that I'm not sure a single query can perform. The subquery does work with those requirements though and shouldn't affect your performance very much given the nature of this particular query.

Comment: If i use the this query `SELECT id FROM kisses ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10`, do you know in PHP PDO statements how can I select the latest result (because it will be the oldest id)? That would be another solution but I don't know how fetch the latest outputted result in PHP PDO..thanks :)

Comment: @MichaelSamuel, are you sure about your statement that the query will return nothing if the table has less than 10 records?  Did you actually try it?  Are you referring to the one with the subquery?  By the way, that's the best approach and you are wrong about subqueries being slow and bad on scaling.

Comment: Hey @DanBracuk :) I'm talking about the second query with no subquery...the one with subquery works fine...regarding subquery a lot of people here confirm that they don't perform well on a large scale...you can read the comments above